# React Native App Navigations working very very slowly

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux, native-base

I have created a React Native App. Currently, I have just created views of the app, no redux as of now. Everything is hardcoded. I have mainly used Cards, Grid, List Views.

I am using `native-base` for designing purpose in my whole app. I contains SideMenu as well which I have created using Drawer of Native Base.

I am using `react-native-router-flux` for navigation.

I am using `react native 0.52.2`.

My App is working really very slowly (taking around 2-3 seconds to navigate) when I am keeping Cards, Grids, ListView on the Pages. If I remove these & just do navigation between pages using Buttons or Side Menu, the App is working fine. I have tested App in Android & iOS real devices & with release build in both the platforms.

Below is my package.json:

```
    {
      "name": "Test",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "test": "jest"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.17.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "native-base": "^2.3.5",
        "react": "16.2.0",
        "react-native": "0.52.2",
        "react-native-action-button": "^2.8.4",
        "react-native-datepicker": "^1.6.0",
        "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.1.17",
        "react-native-modal": "^5.0.0",
        "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.28",
        "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.0.6",
        "react-native-table-component": "^1.1.3",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.5.0",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
        "redux": "^3.7.2",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel-jest": "22.1.0",
        "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
        "jest": "22.1.4",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
      },
      "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
      },
      "rnpm": {
        "assets": [
          "./assets/fonts/"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: Use ```InteractionManager``` to prevent loading of cards and data until screen is displayed. Show mock elements (like Facebook does) until the page is shown

Comment: If you want fast navigation ,use react navigation from wix. To prevent slowness you can remove all console.logs and use more pure components.